# What does Mario say when he's throwing Bowser?

Tags: super-mario-64

I can't fully understand what Mario actually means [when he throws Bowser in to the mine](http://youtu.be/xDhxfUBrMko?t=2m).
It sounds a little blurry, so I hoped someone could translate that for me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

He's saying "[So long(-a), Bowser](http://themushroomkingdom.net/sounds/wav/sm64/sm64_mario_so_long_bowser.wav)".

You can hear the audio clip without the background music on [The Mushroom Kingdom](http://www.themushroomkingdom.net/media/sm64/wav). Basically, it is just saying "So long, Bowser" with a Mario affectation.

Comment: Mario inflection?

Comment: @Arkive Yeah, a Mario 'twist' to it (the "longa" in this case). ;p

Comment: Thanks. I've been wondering this since...1996? Whoa.

Comment: This answer would be improved with an official source.

Comment: My hearing isn't great so it kind of sounds like "so long me baby". Which is why I wanted to look it up in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

[According to](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429124659if_/https://twitter.com/CharlesMartinet/status/1122713913269710848) Mario’s voice actor Charles Martinet himself, he is saying: “So long kinga Bowser!”

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/List_of_Super_Mario_64_and_Super_Mario_64_DS_quotes), Mario says: "So long King Bowser!"

Comment: I always thought it was this, but after listing to the clip linked in @Ktash's answer, and also watching/listening to a clip of the actual fight on YouTube, I have to conclude that Ktash's answer is more correct.

Comment: You have a typo in 'Bowser'.

Comment: You didn't see anything...

Comment: The link no longer says that. That's the danger of citing Wikis.

Comment: Now the page says “So long kinga Bowser!”, presumably because Martinet himself revealed that’s what he was saying there, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like, "So long-a Bowser." That would make sense since he has a stereo-typical Italian accent where "a" is added to the end of most words. Also, if it was meant to be cleaver, "a" in Italian means "to" in English, so Mario could be saying, "So long to Bowser." Just an idea

Comment: I'm an Italian who does not support-a this comment.

Comment: @MacItaly your comment is ok, don't beat yourself up.

Comment: @MacItaly I feel you. As an American, I'm assumed to eat 5 pounds of McDonalds a day.

Answer (score -2):

Mario is italian.  I'm assuming he said "re" bowser or bowsey (italian accent for bowser?)

Re means in italian is king.

So long re-bowsy!